# Software practices - Is it okay to make a method polymorphic using an output argument

Tags: java, design-patterns

We had a use case where a specific request object say `A` must be converted to a class of type `B` or type `C`. For that we wrote static methods `mapToB(A)` and `mapToC(A)`. But wouldn't it be better to have a polymorphic `map` method of type `map(A, B)` and `map(A, C)`. I know that output arguments are considered an anti-pattern, but the `2nd` implementation looks cleaner.

Comment: Java does not have output arguments, and is not polymorphic in return types, so I am not sure how that would work. Is your "output argument" some kind of buffer or template?

Comment: @Thilo For objects, you pass them by reference. If a method accepts an object and that method updates it, then the caller can see the changes!

Comment: Okay, that's what I meant by "buffer" or "template". I vote for not using overloads and sticking with `mapToB` and `mapToC` (also avoids mutable objects).

Comment: Alright @Thilo Also what's your rationale behind it anyway, other than mutability?

Comment: I avoid overloading in general. It is effectively the same as methods with separate names, but has much more potential for confusion.

Comment: why not trying to use the adapter design pattern?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion I would prefer a converter which takes a object of type A and the target type and build the object of the target type for you. I think this is much cleaner than a static method and gives you the possibility to extends the mapping in future if needed. E.g.:

```
class Converter{
    private final objectToConvert;

    public Converter(A objectToConvert){
        this.objectToConvert = objectToConvert;
    }

    public <T> T convert(Class<T> targetType){
        T res;
        // ... Do the convertion
        return res;
    }
}
```

Now you are able to do the convertion in a clean and readable way.

```
A a = new A();

B b = new Converter(a).convert(B.class);
C c = new Converter(a).convert(C.class);
```

Comment: Why wrap an object inside of `Converter` rather than add the `convert(Class<T>)` method directly to class `A`?

Comment: If you add the convert-method to A there will be a direct dependency to all convertable classes (B, C and future classes) in A. This isn't good if the classes B and/or C are changed or become deprecated. If this part is moved to the converter only the converter is affected from changes. This is more cleaner and leaves A untouched.
Additional to that, I think taht A shouldn't know the process to convert itself to an other class.

Answer (score 0):

> But wouldn't it be better to have a polymorphic map method of type
>   map(A, B) and map(A, C)

You could have something of near :

```
 <T> T map(Object source, Class<T> target)
```

Where `source` is any Object and `target` the class of the instance to return.

For example :

```
public class Mapper {

    public static <T> T map(Object source, Class<T> target) {
        T converted = null;
        // ...
        return converted;
    }
}
```

And you can call it :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(...);
MyOtherClass myOtherClass = Mapper.map(myClass, MyOtherClass.class);
```